# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider at API Level below 21

Tags: android, firebase

I use Firebase Analytics and Crash in my App. The problem is, that on api level 19 and below, I can't start the application anyway. What can I do?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jeddsan.net.einkaufsliste"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.6.0-18"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Logfile:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: jeddsan.net.einkaufsliste, PID: 15916
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/jeddsan.net.einkaufsliste-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/jeddsan.net.einkaufsliste-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5236)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4828)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4711)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/jeddsan.net.einkaufsliste-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/jeddsan.net.einkaufsliste-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4828) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4711) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The other solutions on StackOverflow didn't helped me.

Thanks for every response.

Comment: Try removing `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'`.
It's still in beta and has some bugs. I also had problems with it.

Comment: Version 9.4.0 works fine for me. Try that if you don't need any new features in 9.6.x.

Comment: Make sure you have made the [manifest changes needed for MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle).  If MultiDex is correctly configured you will see `logcat` messages during app  init like this one: `I/MultiDex: install done`